# .NET 6 logging to file

Tags: logging, .net-6.0

I'm upgrading a .NET core application that uses MS logging to .NET 6.  Before it was configured to log to a file with appsettings.json looking like below:

```
"Logging": {
    "LogFileName": "{MMddyyyy}.log",
    "LogFilePath": "E:\\Logs",   
    "MaxLogFileSize": 20,
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information"
    }
```

Looks like the LogFileName and other attributes under Logging are invalid now.  Where do I put these attributes now?  I tried "Debug" but that doesn't write to a file.

Comment: What is MS logging? As far as I know, there is no out-of-the-box logger in .NET Core which logs to a file. So if it worked before, that already was a 3rd party logger.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is not provided by .NET 6 OOTB any longer.  Need to use a 3rd party logger to log to a file now.